# Is there a way to decompose a CNN model to provide prediction insights to humans?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a CNN that after a lot of work is now performing multiclass (8) classification at 99% accuracy.

While the classification itself has a lot of value, going to a prediction engine would be a game changer.

The catch is that the ability to predict is needed by a human in real life (IRL), not in being processed by a computer.

In this case the CNN is able to classify things faster than the human. It would be significant if the model could provide insights into how it is classifying things

Is there any way to decompose a Keras CNN model and/or it's weights to glean how it's arriving at it's decision?  I don't believe so, but would hate not to ask and find out it's possible.

It's not that I'm looking for it to be exact, but if I can find one or two things that heavily influence the prediction/classification that a human being could key on, that could be significant.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are a lot of methods, unfortunately asking to recommend or list methods is off-topic here. Also this is not really a programming problem.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm pretty new to posting here, but I've basically learned how to code here. Is there a place where this question would be better suited?  My Google searches aren't yielding a lot of fruit.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to decompose a Keras CNN model and/or it's weights to glean how it's arriving at it's decision?

You can look at the [Grad-CAM algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391) to see where the neural network was looking at before taking its final decision. Here's an [implementation in Keras](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) using a pre-trained model.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from IPython.display import Image, display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

model_builder = keras.applications.xception.Xception
img_size = (299, 299)
preprocess_input = keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input
decode_predictions = keras.applications.xception.decode_predictions

last_conv_layer_name = "block14_sepconv2_act"
classifier_layer_names = [
    "avg_pool",
    "predictions",
]

img_path = keras.utils.get_file(
    "african_elephant.jpg", "https://i.imgur.com/Bvro0YD.png"
)

display(Image(img_path))


def get_img_array(img_path, size):
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=size)
    array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
    return array


def make_gradcam_heatmap(
    img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names
):

    last_conv_layer = model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name)
    last_conv_layer_model = keras.Model(model.inputs, last_conv_layer.output)

    classifier_input = keras.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape[1:])
    x = classifier_input
    for layer_name in classifier_layer_names:
        x = model.get_layer(layer_name)(x)
    classifier_model = keras.Model(classifier_input, x)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_model(img_array)
        tape.watch(last_conv_layer_output)
        preds = classifier_model(last_conv_layer_output)
        top_pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        top_class_channel = preds[:, top_pred_index]

    grads = tape.gradient(top_class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output.numpy()[0]
    pooled_grads = pooled_grads.numpy()
    for i in range(pooled_grads.shape[-1]):
        last_conv_layer_output[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads[i]

    heatmap = np.mean(last_conv_layer_output, axis=-1)
    heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0) / np.max(heatmap)
    return heatmap

img_array = preprocess_input(get_img_array(img_path, size=img_size))

model = model_builder(weights="imagenet")

preds = model.predict(img_array)
print("Predicted:", decode_predictions(preds, top=1)[0])

heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(
    img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names
)

img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path)
img = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)

heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)

jet = cm.get_cmap("jet")

jet_colors = jet(np.arange(256))[:, :3]
jet_heatmap = jet_colors[heatmap]

jet_heatmap = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(jet_heatmap)
jet_heatmap = jet_heatmap.resize((img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
jet_heatmap = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(jet_heatmap)

superimposed_img = jet_heatmap * 0.4 + img
superimposed_img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(superimposed_img)

save_path = "elephant_cam.jpg"
superimposed_img.save(save_path)

display(Image(save_path))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into it now.